# Why would Aiz Wallenstein be upset upon being called "Aria"?

Tags: danmachi

In DanMachi Sword Oratoria anime, Ep. 5 and 6, a woman with red hair called Aiz "Aria". For some reason this makes Aiz upset. Do we know why Aiz got upset being called Aria?

Comment: According to [DanMachi Wiki](http://danmachi.wikia.com/wiki/Aria), Aria was her mother.

Comment: @Zereges yes she is her mother, but why would calling Aiz with her mother's name made her upset?

Answer (score 3):

As I don't have enough reputation just yet to comment however I'd like to point out a few things. These are solely speculations based on the manga and anime as no definitive answer is not yet known

- Ais is Aria's daughter however spirits are not capable of having offspring in the series. Hence the method of Ais's Birth is Unexplained and it could be something which hurts her.
- People often confuse the two as they are totally identical in appearance so much that even Revis got confused.
- There is a theory going around which suggests that Ais maybe Aria's reincarnation however it was countered on this archived subreddit- https://www.reddit.com/r/DanMachi/comments/6wj7ta/theory_aiz_and_bells_true_colors/?utm_source=ui&utm_medium=amp&utm_name=amp_revamp&utm_term=nh&utm_content=post_body

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, Aria is most likely being held hostage by the One-Eyed Black Dragon. This quote from the wiki reinforces this: "Aria lived with Albert and Ais long before the start of the story until their battle against the One Eyed Black Dragon, after which her fate is unknown" ([Wiki](https://danmachi.fandom.com/wiki/Aria))

At the least, Aria is most likely not dead. So, if Aiz is aware of this, then it would make sense that any reminder of her mother would also make her remember the death of her father—who is certainly "Deceased" ([Wiki](https://danmachi.fandom.com/wiki/Albert_Waldstein)), rather than simply "Status Unknown" like Aria.

Therefore, it follows that Aiz would feel hatred towards the OEBD when a stimulus makes her recall this memory, which would inevitably arouse her anger no matter the situation. An example is that Aiz becomes enraged whenever she fights against any type of dragon—infant, Valgang, even Wiene.

My point is, she is recalling past trauma connected to her mother and her hatred for the OEBD. This would also explain her illogical actions when facing dragons—"she launched herself to the 12th Floor to face Infant Dragons despite how dangerous they were" ([Wiki](https://danmachi.fandom.com/wiki/Ais_Wallenstein)).